# How to show progressbar while loading image from device gallery to imageView

Tags: android, android-progressbar

In my android app I have included an option to upload image from device gallery. Its take some time to load so I want to include a progressbar. I used `spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` method but its not working. I attached my code snippets

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
        switch(requestCode) { 
            case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();
                        //Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-
                        spinner = (ProgressBar) img1.findViewById(R.id.loading);
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                        img =bos.toByteArray();

           } }  }
```

xml photos

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="Add" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
         <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Please help me to correct the code..

Comment: as far as I remember onActivityResult is run on the UI thread, maybe try migrating everything to an asynctask?

Answer (score 2):

Use AsyncTask

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

private ProgressBar progressBar;

public MyTask( ProgressBar progressBar ) {

    this.progressBar= progressBar;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground( String... params ) {
    progressBar.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    //do your work
    return "OK";
   }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<Comment> result ) {
    progressBar.setVisibility( View.GONE );
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner = (ProgressBar) img1.findViewById(R.id.loading);
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Are you sure that this is not working?
It seems that it's not enough time for user to see difference in UI.
Maybe operations inside `spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE)` just really fast?

Comment: while loading image from gallery to imageview there is a delay inbetween and when I run the code app is stopped after selecting image from gallery